# Почему не работает кнопка загрузки фото

Tags: yii2

Проблема заключается в том, что после выбора картинки, и нажатии кнопки "upload" вообще ничего не происходит, и ещё когда я выбираю вторую картинку, ту что я выбрал первой пропадает и заменяется второй, хоть такого не должно происходить.

Контроллер:

```
class PhotoController extends Controller
{
  private $service;

  public function __construct( $id, $module, array $config = [], 
  PhotoManageService $service )
  {
      $this->service = $service;
      parent::__construct( $id, $module, $config );
  }

  public function actionCreate()
  {
    $form = new PhotoForm();
    if ($form->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $form->validate()){
      try{
        $this->service->addPhotos($form);
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'photo uploaded');
        return $this->goHome();
      }catch(\RuntimeException $e){
        Yii::$app->errorHandler->logException($e);
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash($e->getMessage());
     }
    }

   return $this->render('create', ['model' => $form]);

 }

}
```

Модель:

```
class Photo extends ActiveRecord
{

    public static function create(UploadedFile $file):self
    {
        $photo = new static();
        $photo->file = $file;
        return $photo;
    }

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%photo}}';
    }

    public function behaviors() {
        return [
      [
          'class' => ImageUploadBehavior::className(),
          'attribute' => 'file',
          'createThumbsOnRequest' => true,
          'filePath' => '@staticRoot/origin/[[pk]].[[extension]]',
          'fileUrl' => '@static/origin/[[pk]].[[extension]]',
          'thumbPath' => '@staticRoot/cache/[[profile]]_[[pk]].[[extension]]',
          'thumbUrl' => '@static/cache/[[profile]]_[[pk]].[[extension]]',
           'thumbs' => [
              'admin' => ['width' => 100, 'height' => 70],
              'thumb' => ['width' => 640, 'height' => 480]
        ],
      ],
    ];
  }

}
```

Вид:

```
<div class="box box-default">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'enableClientValidation' => false,
        'options' => ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']
    ]); ?>
    <div class="box-body">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'files[]')->widget(FileInput::class, [
            'options' => [
            'accept' => 'image/*',
            'multiple' => true,
        ]
         ])
       ?>
   </div>

   <? ActiveForm::end();?>
</div>
```

Форма:

```
class PhotoForm extends Model
{

    /**
     * @var UploadedFile[]
     */
    public $files;

    public function rules() {
        return [
            ['files', 'each', 'rule' => ['image']],
        ];
    }

    public function beforeValidate(): bool
    {
        if (parent::beforeValidate()){
        $this->files = UploadedFile::getInstances($this, 'files');
        return true;
        }
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: покажите класс `PhotoManageService`

Comment: Вообще у вас какие-то странные манипуляции с изображениями в коде происходят. Складывается такое ощущение, что вы накрутили каких-то плагинов, но при этом используете стандартные способы загрузки, но с непонятным дублированием и прочее.

Comment: Плюс к этому в Вашем коде я не нашел ни одного $this->files->saveAs() - то есть метода физического сохранения файла, это метод класса `UploadedFile`, возможно эти манипуляции проводятся в `ImageUploadBehavior`, но кода этого класса нет в вопросе. На Вашем месте я бы все переписал, потому что на данном этапе код выглядит слегка макаронным и Вы явно не понимаете, как он должен работать

Comment: [Вот тут код, который вам нужен](https://bitbucket.org/Maxemp/blog/src/75e1669063aa9db56f3ee5cf0c182b2ed3750c97/blog/manage/PhotoManageService.php?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мой код не работал из-за того, что я во вьюшке в `<? ActiveForm::end();?>` не добавил php т.е. должно быть вот так `<?php ActiveForm::end();?>`